# issue recognizing NEs with StanfordNER in python NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

This happens when there is a potential NE followed by a comma, for example if my strings are something like,

> "These names  Praveen Kumar,,  David Harrison,  Paul Harrison, blah "

or

> "California, United States"

my output is something as follows, respectively.

> [[(u'These', u'O'), (u'names', u'O'), (u'Praveen', u'O'), (u'Kumar,,', u'O'), (u'David', u'PERSON'), (u'Harrison,', u'O'), (u'Paul', u'PERSON'), (u'Harrison,', u'O'), (u'blah', u'O')]]

or

> [[(u'California,', u'O'), (u'United', u'LOCATION'), (u'States', u'LOCATION')]]

why it doesn't recognize potential NEs such as "Praveen Kumar", "Harrison" and "California"?

Here is how is use it in the code:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import NERTagger
st = NERTagger('stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', 'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')

tags = st.tag("California, United States".split())
```

Is it because I tokenize the input stirng with `split()` ? How can I resolve this as it's working fine when tried in Java?

Comment: First, `from nltk import word_tokenize`, then `st.tag(word_tokenize("California, United States"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing this through the nltk, use its tokenizers to split your input:

```
alltext = myfile.read()
tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(alltext)
```

**Edit:** You're probably better off with the stanford toolkit's own tokenizer, as recommended by the other answer.  So if you'll be feeding the tokens to one of the Stanford tools, tokenize your text like this to get exactly the tokenization that the tools expect:

```
from nltk.tokenize.stanford import StanfordTokenizer
tokenize = StanfordTokenizer().tokenize

alltext = myfile.read()
tokenized_text = tokenize(alltext)
```

To use this method you'll need to have the Stanford tools installed, and the nltk must be able to find them. I assume you have already taken care of this, since you're using the Stanford NER tool.

Comment: should be just enough to use word_tokenize as it does sent_tokenize inside of it? http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html

Comment: You're right! It didn't use to be the case in version 2: `word_tokenize` would occasionally give different tokens at sentence boundaries if called on the whole text. I like the new design :-)

Answer (score 1):

The commas need to be separate tokens.  Just using split() is not accomplishing this, so the NER tagger is not recognizing a token like "California,".

If you want to get similar behavior to using Stanford CoreNLP in Java, I'd suggest using the nltk wrapper for tokenization: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/stanford.html